# push elements selected into one object

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-props

I have a component called "itemSelection" and another one called "Item"

in the itemSelection i just map through an api response like this

```
<div className="row">
                {this.state.items.map(i => <Item name={i.name} quantity={i.quantity} />)}
            </div>
```

in the "Item" component I have like 3 card item with a select button. in its state there is also "quantity" key but that's for the quantity selected by the user of a specific item. So, what I'm try to achieve here is if the user selected one item and quantity of 2, I want to take that in an object and put that object in an array,  and if the user selected another item with quantity of 3, I want that in another object and just push that object in the array where I have put the first object to be something like that

```
[{name: first item, quantity: 2}, {name: second item, quantity: 3}]
```

here is what I tried

```
targetValue = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      let qua = e.target.textContent;
      this.setState({quantity: qua, selected: true});
      const newQuantity = {name: this.props.name, quantity: qua}
      const quantities = [...this.state.quantities];
      quantities.push(newQuantity);
      this.setState({quantities});
      console.log(quantities);
    }
```

The function above is included in the "Item.js" and here is the return function

```
<div className="col-md-4">
                    <div className={"card " + (this.state.selected ? "frame" : "")} style={{width: 18+'rem'}}>
                      <img className="card-img-top" style={{width: 10+'rem', margin: 0+' '+'auto'}} src={this.props.img} alt="Card image cap"/>
                      <div className="card-body">
                        <h5 className="card-title">{this.props.name}</h5>
                        <p clasNames="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
                        <div className="description">
                            <p className="card-text">30€</p>
                            <p className={"card-text " + (this.state.selected ? "" : "displayQua")}>Q: {this.state.quantity}</p>
                        </div>
                        <button onClick={this.toggleMenu} href="#" style={{width: 100 + '%', margin: 0+' '+'auto'}}  className="btn">SELECT</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="menu">
                        <div className={this.state.visible ? "" : "visible"}>
                            <div className="menu">
                                {_.times(this.props.quantity, i => (
                                    <a onClick={this.targetValue} key={i} href="#">{i + 1}</a>
                                  ))}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Can you post more code?

Comment: I just posted the related code to my question, I don't think anything else would make any sense, are you looking for something specific in my code?

Comment: Well you don't show any relation between the Item and ItemSelection components.

Comment: Edited. it's just a simple component for the single item in the itemSelection component

Answer (score 0):

The question you have asked is a bit unclear. But as far as I understand there could be 2 issues :

1. Change `const quantities = [...this.state.quantities];` to `let quantities = [...this.state.quantities];` since you'll be pushing new values to the array.
2. `let qua = e.target.textContent;` not sure if this is the best way to get the value. Try `let qua = e.target.value;` and pass the value param in anchor tag `<a onClick={this.targetValue} value={i+1} key={i} href="#">{i + 1}</a>`

Sharing the output for what you tried will definitely help to understand better.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I changed const to let but the output is still the same just just an array of one object container the name of the item and the quantity and when I select another item it just create another array with an object of the name of the item and the quantity like this [{name: "example", quantity: 2}]

Comment: Yes it does but for just the same item, when you select different quantities for the same item it will be something like this [{name: "example1", quantity: "2"},{name: "example1", quantity: "5"},{name: "example1", quantity: "3"}], but what if there like 3 items I pick some item with a quantity and another item with a quantity. the objects of both item doesn't make it to the same array but with 2 different arrays

Comment: Could you create a sandbox and i'll take a look at it. This seems like a design problem in the application.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to push elements to a state array in React. You can do this

```
   const newQuantity = {name: this.props.name, quantity: qua};
   this.setState(previousState => ({
       quantities : [...previousState.quantities, newQuantity]
   }));
```

Also don’t use multiple setStates inside handler function use one that’s enough :)